# SCALA: external command "mail" with "subject"

Tags: linux, scala, email

I'd like to send email from scala using Linux external command "mail".
The command execution works, just I have troubles setting the Subject string, here some tentatives:

**SENT OK**

```
scala> val email="me@email.it"
  email: String = me@email.it
scala> val result = "echo ECCO" #| s"mail -s ciao_bello $email " !
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
result: Int = 0
```

**SENT but Subject:  ciao**

```
scala> val subject="ciao bello !"
  subject: String = ciao bello !
scala> val result = "echo BODY" #| s"mail -s $subject $email " !
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
rewrite: excessive recursion (max 50), ruleset Canonify2
result: Int = 0
```

**SENT but Subject:  "ciao"**

```
scala> val subject= "\"ciao bello !\""
  subject: String = "ciao bello !"
scala> val result = "echo BODY" #| s"mail -s $subject $email " !
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
!"... Unbalanced '"'
result: Int = 0
```

**NOT SENT**

```
scala> val result = "echo BODY" #| s"mail -s \"ciao bello\" $email " !
<console>:10: error: value ciao is not a member of `enter code here`scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
       val result = "echo BODY" #| s"mail -s \"ciao bello\" $email " !                                               
<console>:10: error: not found: value bello
       val result = "echo BODY" #| s"mail -s \"ciao bello\" $email " !
```

How can I deal with subjects containing more than a word?

Comment: I majorly improved the code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Some loser gave me the solution but just an adjustment before having email sent correctly:

```
scala> val subject="\"ciao bello !\""
subject: String = "ciao bello !"

scala> val result = Seq("sh", "-c", s"echo BODY | mail -s $subject $email") !
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
result: Int = 0
```

Thanks and cheers!